# Using Ajax to call a Yii2 function on button click

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

After trying some possible solutions that I found through internet/other questions here, I can't seem to find the problem with my code. What I need is that, after clicking a button in my view, an action in my Yii2 controller gets called through Ajax and performs some action. However, with my current code, after clicking the button nothing seems to happen.

The relevant code is as follows...

The view:

```
(...)
Html::button('Eliminar', ['data-confirm' => '¿Eliminar enunciado?', 'onclick' => '
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/evaluacion/eliminar-enunciado",
        data: {
            id: '.$enunciado->id.'
        }, success: function(result) {
            if(result == 1) {
                $.pjax.reload({container: "#construccion-evaluacion"});
            } else {
            }
        }, error: function(result) {
            console.log(\"server error\");
        }
    });
'])
(...)
```

The controller:

```
(...)
public function actionEliminarEnunciado($id)
{
    Enunciado::findOne($id)->delete();
    if(Enunciado::findOne($id) != null) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
(...)
```

Some considerations for clarification:
 - The controller file is called EvaluacionController.php.
 - The $enunciado->id variable is properly defined and has a valid value.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If youre using Chrome - press F12, point to Network tab and see result of your ajax call. Propably its `400 - Bad Request`, because in action you defined param `$id` but youre sending it by `POST` method. So change URL of ajax and add `id`, or remove `$id` from function declaration and get `$id` by `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need get value of POST request;

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
    $id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: This and Yupik's comment helped me to solve it. I would like to point out that I actually had one more typo in the controller as well: the action should return 1 or 0, not echo them. Thanks!